# When dealing with Localizable.stringsdict, why String.localizedStringWithFormat is able to produce different output with same input?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `Localizable.stringsdict` as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>archived_template</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@VARIABLE@</string>
        <key>VARIABLE</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>u</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>Note archived</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%1$d archived</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>clear_lock_message_template</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@VARIABLE@</string>
        <key>VARIABLE</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>u</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%u locked note will be permanently deleted!!!</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%u locked notes will be permanently deleted!!!</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am surprised that, even the same input `%#@VARIABLE@` is provided to `String.localizedStringWithFormat`, it is capable to produce different output.

```
//
// CASE 1: clear_lock_message_template
//
var formatString : String = NSLocalizedString("clear_lock_message_template", comment: "")
print("formatString : " + formatString)
var resultString : String = String.localizedStringWithFormat(formatString, 1)
print("resultString : " + resultString)

print()

formatString = NSLocalizedString("clear_lock_message_template", comment: "")
print("formatString : " + formatString)
resultString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(formatString, 2)
print("resultString : " + resultString)

print()

//
// CASE 2: archived_template
//
formatString = NSLocalizedString("archived_template", comment: "")
print("formatString : " + formatString)
resultString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(formatString, 1)
print("resultString : " + resultString)

print()

formatString = NSLocalizedString("archived_template", comment: "")
print("formatString : " + formatString)
resultString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(formatString, 2)
print("resultString : " + resultString)
```

The output

```
formatString : %#@VARIABLE@
resultString : 1 locked note will be permanently deleted!!!

formatString : %#@VARIABLE@
resultString : 2 locked notes will be permanently deleted!!!

formatString : %#@VARIABLE@
resultString : Note archived

formatString : %#@VARIABLE@
resultString : 2 archived
```

For **CASE 1: clear_lock_message_template** and **CASE 2: archived_template**, we are using `%#@VARIABLE@` as `String.localizedStringWithFormat` input.

But, why they are capable of producing different right output?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand which part of the output surprises you. Can you be specific?

Comment: @matt  For case 1 and case 2, both seems to be executing same code `String.localizedStringWithFormat("%#@VARIABLE@", 1)`. Why are they capable to produce different (and correct) output?

Comment: Because clear_lock_message_template and archived_template are different strings?

Comment: But u can see I print them (`formatString`) out. Their value is `%#@VARIABLE@`

Comment: No, their _description_ is `%#@VARIABLE@`. That tells what key to use. But there is more information in an NSLocalizedString than that. It isn't _just_ a simple string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *description* of all the `formatString` values is the same. But they are *not* the same object. The value you get back from NSLocalizedString by looking in a *.stringsdict* is not a mere string! It is in fact a secret object type, an `__NSLocalizedString` — or, as I like to call it, an NSLocalizedString.

Let's examine one of yours (using Objective-C):

[image]

What's this??? It turns out that, under the hood, an NSLocalizedString carries the whole *.stringsdict* corresponding `<dict>` entry inside it. And you can see why. That way, the inner key name (i.e. `VARIABLE`) can be used to look up the desired information *in that dictionary*.

So one of your format strings effectively carries this whole dictionary inside itself:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@VARIABLE@</string>
    <key>VARIABLE</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>u</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>Note archived</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%1$d archived</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Meanwhile, the other one carries a completely different dictionary, namely this:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@VARIABLE@</string>
    <key>VARIABLE</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>u</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>%u locked note will be permanently deleted!!!</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%u locked notes will be permanently deleted!!!</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

You can't see this information with simple `print` in Swift, because this object pretends to be a String. Nevertheless, as we can see, it holds this extra info within itself. So as a result, when you then call `String.localizedStringWithFormat` using that "format string" (the NSLocalizedString object), that call just looks right into that internal dictionary to look up the corresponding information for the VARIABLE key.

This architecture, besides being ingeniously clever, is a good thing, because otherwise every single inner key name would have to be unique!